# How to tell “union all” which table to actually select?

Tags: sql

In a table, if I have a “table_ID” column, and an “entity_ID” column, how do I express “SELECT * FROM (SELECT table FROM all_tables WHERE table_ID = ?) where key = entity_ID”?

This question is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799897/select-table-to-select-from-dependent-on-column-value-of-already-given-table), but it’s not efficient *for our use-case*:

The problem I have with the answer above is that we will have hundreds of tables (types), and the key can only ever be (once) in a single table. Can I somehow modify the “union all” such that it uses the “type_ID” to optimize away all selects that cannot possibly contain the key? What if I define a view for each table, that adds a constant “table ID” column to each table? Would that be enough to "optimize away" all selects but one?

Why do this? Because we already have above *2M LOC* that assumes this data model! Please read on:

We currently use an OODBMS, which is now „deprecated“. We have deep a inheritance hierarchy of entities (everything extends the same base entity), and the OODBMS lets use mix freely „serialised objects“ with entities, and sorts out automatically that entity references are replaced with „handles“ when serialising. It offers a single “key space” for all entities, and supports accessing multiple DBs in a single transaction, by putting the “DB ID” (16-bits) into the entity ID (64-bits). All you need to do to define a new entity is extend an existing entity class, and possibly specify some fields as “indexed”. Fields can also be freely added or removed from existing entity types. In short, it “Just Works” and it’s extremely convenient compared to using an ORM.

We should now replace our DB (because it’s deprecated), and “from the top” comes the order that “all new projects shall use PostgreSQL”. Our model is a terrible fit for an ORM API, so I am considering alternatives that match our existing data model. My current plan is to use one table per concrete type, and no explicit foreign key definition (we had none before; we only got an exception when “resolving” a bad entity ID). The “entity ID” would be replaced with one “smallint” db-ID, one “smallint” table-ID (type-ID), and an “integer” as entity-ID within that type/table (most entities “last for ever”, and if ever we created more than 4B entities of the same type, we would just use a second type-ID and table for the same type).
With such a model we could keep our codebase relatively unchanged.

Comment: postgreSQL is a very good choice IMHO. You didn't give any samples to make the scenario understandable abut anyway look at inheritance in postgreSQL. Looks like that is what you are asking for.

Comment: `"From the top" comes the order`.  Seems to me that it might be worth it to present a use-case to the top for allowing a switch to another OODBMS. If it's a good fit for replacing that deprecated OODBMS.  Which one are you using now btw?

Comment: Wanting to keep the existing data model is a good idea, if it was *well designed* and didn't tie itself to too many specifics of a storage architecture. Unfortunately, it doesn't sound (from what I can pull out of your description) that this is the case. At the very least, make sure that there's awareness of the technical debt that you'll be left with of trying to adapt a data model that expects one architecture to a storage solution that offers a different one.

Comment: @LukStorms We are Using Versant JVI (now owned by Actian). The DB will on, but the JVI API is now in "maintainance mode". They have moved to JPA, but do not offer a migration path.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Wait, what? I had no clue you could do that! I think that classifies as an "alternative" answer. Presumably better than what I had in mind.